# JAXB and property ordering with list of elements

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I am using JAXB to unmarshall xml file.
here is my code for the element feature, but I wanna have a special order of the elements in the element feature, like this

```
<feature>
  <name>2D Polynomial Approximation of Log of ConstantQ</name>
  <active>false</active>
  <attribute>50</attribute>
  <attribute>20</attribute>
  <attribute>10</attribute>
  <attribute>10</attribute>
</feature>
```

I checked some tutorial of @XmlType(propOrder = {}), but I cannot find a way to order with list of elements like the attribute elements here.

here is my codes

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "feature")
@XmlType(propOrder = {"name", "active","attribute"})
public class Feature{

    String name;

    boolean active;

    List<String> attributes = new LinkedList<String>();

    /**
     * name element of feature element
     * @return
     */
    @XmlElement(name = "name")
    public final String getName(){
        return this.name;
    }

    public final void setName(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    /**
     * active element
     * @return
     */
    @XmlElement(name = "active")
    public final boolean getActive(){
        return this.active;
    }

    public final void setActive(boolean active){
        this.active = active;
    }

    /**
     * attribute elements
     * @return
     */
    @XmlElement(name = "attribute")
    public final List<String> getAttributes(){
        return this.attributes;
    }

    public final void setAttributes(List<String> attributes){
        this.attributes = attributes;
    }
}
```

It always throw out exception, since I only define one attribute in propOrder. But since the attribute is multiple, could be one or more, I do not have any idea to implement it.
Or do you know some other way to order the elements

Thanks for your help in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `propOrder` is based on the field/property name and not the XML element name.  So you should have

```
@XmlType(propOrder = {"name", "active","attributes"})
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/02/jaxbs-xmltype-and-proporder.html

Comment: Hey, Blaise, Thnks, could you explain me more details about how to implement it?

Comment: @ZYJ - I have added what you need to change the `propOrder` to.